# Returning column with count of 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that looks up a list of documents depending on their department and their status.

```
DECLARE @StatusIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5';
DECLARE @DepartmentId NVARCHAR(2) = 'IT';

SELECT ILDPST.name,
       COUNT(*) AS TodayCount
FROM dbo.TableA ILDP
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB ILDPS ON ILDPS.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId = ILDP.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableC ILDPST ON ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId = ILDPS.CurrentStateTypeId
WHERE (ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId = @DepartmentId OR @DepartmentId IS NULL)
    AND ILDPS.CurrentStateTypeId IN (
        SELECT value
        FROM dbo.StringAsIntTable(@StatusIds)
    )
GROUP BY ILDPST.name;
```

This returns the results:

[image]

However, I'd also like to be able to return statuses where the `TodayCount` is equal to 0 (i.e. any status with an id included in `@StatusIds` should be returned, regardless of `TodayCount`).

I've tried messing with some unions / joins / ctes but I couldn't quite get it to work. I'm not much of an SQL person so not sure what else to provide that could be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Which table does not have the corresponding records in it for the `@StatusIds` ? You're already outer joining so it should be fine, unless it is `TableA` which is causing the record to be excluded, in which case you'll need to re-order the tables in the join.

Comment: Note: `(ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId = @DepartmentId OR @DepartmentId IS NULL)` can be written as `(ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId = IsNull( @DepartmentId, ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId )`

Comment: @shadow I will not recommand that, it will give slightly slower performance

Comment: @t-clausen.dk So so true! Just tested on a table with 303.423 rows. With IsNull results returned in ~10" and with or xxx is null in ~3". Thanks friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @StatusIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5';
DECLARE @DepartmentId NVARCHAR(2) = 'IT';

SELECT ILDPST.name,
       COUNT(ILDP.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId) AS TodayCount
FROM 
  dbo.TableC ILDPST 
  LEFT JOIN
    dbo.TableB ILDPS ON ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId = ILDPS.CurrentStateTypeId
  LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.TableA ILDP ON ILDPS.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId = ILDP.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId
  AND (ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId = @DepartmentId OR @DepartmentId IS NULL)
WHERE 
    ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId
    IN (
         SELECT value
         FROM dbo.StringAsIntTable(@StatusIds)
       )
GROUP BY ILDPST.name;
```

Comment: @Y.B. you are absolutely right, this has been corrected and I am ashamed

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have all the records from TableC you need to left join all other tables to it, not left join it to the other tables. Also it's best to `INNER JOIN` the filtering table you create from `@StatusIds` rather then apply it through `IN`clause. Try this:

```
DECLARE @StatusIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5';
DECLARE @DepartmentId NVARCHAR(2) = 'IT';

SELECT ILDPST.Name, COUNT(ILDP.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId) AS TodayCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM dbo.StringAsIntTable(@StatusIds)) StatusIds
INNER JOIN dbo.TableC ILDPST
  ON ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId = StatusIds.value
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB ILDPS
  ON ILDPS.CurrentStateTypeId = ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableA ILDP
  ON ILDP.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId = ILDPS.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId
 AND (ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId = @DepartmentId OR @DepartmentId IS NULL)
GROUP BY ILDPST.Name;
```

Comment: You can't have a left join and put a condition to that joined table in the WHERE clause. It cancels the LEFT JOIN making it an INNER JOIN(except when @DepartmentId is NULL)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Please note this condition is in `ON` clause. There is no `WHERE` clause at all.

Comment: I don't know how I misread that, my appology. There are some other issues though. COUNT(ILDP,*) is invalid and duplicates in the nvarchar StatusIds will cause duplicated data

Comment: @t-clausen.dk You are right. Thank you. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function to create a table value for your status id's.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
(
    @myString varchar(max),
    @deliminator varchar(2)
)
RETURNS 
@ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    [Part] [varchar](max) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
        Declare @iSpaces int
        Declare @part varchar(max)

        --initialize spaces
        Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
        While @iSpaces > 0

        Begin
            Select @part = substring(@myString,0,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0))

            Insert Into @ReturnTable(Part)
            Select @part

    Select @myString = substring(@mystring,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)+ len(@deliminator),len(@myString) - charindex(' ',@myString,0))


            Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
        end

        If len(@myString) > 0
            Insert Into @ReturnTable
            Select @myString

    RETURN 
END
```

This can now be used as a table that you can LEFT JOIN to.

```
DECLARE @StatusIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5';

SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@StatusIds, ',')
```

Comment: I believe they already use this function under `dbo.StringAsIntTable` name. :-)

Comment: Ah yes missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not tested but give it a try:

```
;With Cte ( Value ) As
( Select Distinct Value From dbo.StringAsIntTable( @StatusIds ) )
Select
    ILDPST.name,
    COUNT(*) AS TodayCount
From
    dbo.TableC              As ILDPST
    Inner Join Cte                      On ( ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId = Cte.Value )                                            
    Left Join dbo.TableB    As ILDPS    On ( ILDPST.IntranetLoanDealPreStateTypeId = ILDPS.CurrentStateTypeId )
    Left Join dbo.TableA    As ILDP     On ( ILDPS.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId = ILDP.IntranetLoanDealPreStateId )
                                            And ( ( ILDP.CreatedByDepartmentId = @DepartmentId ) Or ( @DepartmentId Is Null ) ) 
Group By
    ILDPST.name
```

Comment: CTE is a nice idea, but I believe it still must be explicitly mentioned either in `From` or `Join` clause.

Comment: @Y.B. It is joined with table `dbo.TableB`. Instead of using `where xxx in ( select .. )`.

Comment: as @Y.B. correctly said, you can't refer to columns in CTE without refering to it like you would using a normal table(FROM or JOIN)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Jesussss... Now I saw the problem. What an ass#$@#$le! Thanks guys. I will correct it in script.

Comment: @shadow Cte filtering would be incapacitated by `LEFT JOIN`. and as @t-clausen.dk commented on my answer previously there can be duplicates in @StatusIds that would have no effect in the original solution, but would crop up in `JOIN`.